# Template parse errors in Angular4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to separate the declaration of components. I've created a new file called "Components.ts" and I wrote the declaration codes there and I'm exporting It.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Component1} from '../components/Component1.component';
import { Component2} from '../components/Component2.component';
import { Component3} from 
'../components/Component3.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Component1,
    Component2,
    Component3
  ] 
})

export class Components { }
```

And I'm defining into my "App.module.ts" file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Components } from './Misc/Components';//Custom Module


@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent], //This is my main component
    imports: [
       Components  // This is the custom module containg declarations of 
                   // other components
    ],
```

Here is the error:
[image]

**UPDATE**
I've already Imported ReactiveForm Module.

My project is running fine if i define all the components in the "App.module.ts" file like this:

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Component1,
    Component2,
    Component3
  ];
```

Problem occurs when i'm trying to seperate the declarations of all other components.

Comment: so what is the error

Comment: It says "Template parse error" in the console. Meaning it cannot load those components.  I may have done something wrong here.

Comment: @JaowatRaihan provide plunker or stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You need to export those components since you want to use it to other modules

And base in the error you need to import ReactiveFormsModule since you're using formGroup and CommonModule since you're using ngIf

Do it like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { NewComponentComponent } from '../components/Component1.component';
import { New2Component } from '../components/Component2.component';
import { ChildComponentComponent } from 
'../components/Component3.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    Component1,
    Component2,
    Component3
  ],
 exports: [
    Component1,
    Component2,
    Component3
  ] 
})

export class Components { }
```

Comment: Changed it. Still same problem.

Comment: did you use ngIf or ngFor on those components? if yes then you forgot to import CommonModule in Components

Comment: Yes i've used ngif and ngfor on Component1. Now I imported CommonModule in Component.ts file. But where should I use it? Because importing this module is not changing anything

Comment: You need to import ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: Update your Component module

Answer (score 0):

you need to add [declarable](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#the-declarations-array) classes to an `NgModule's` declarations list, not the file name.

Every element defined in the `declarations` array is private by default. use `Exports` property and you should only export whatever the other modules in our application need to perform its job.

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { NewComponentComponent } from '../components/Component1.component';
    import { New2Component } from '../components/Component2.component';
    import { ChildComponentComponent } from 
    '../components/Component3.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        NewComponentComponent,
        New2Component,
        ChildComponentComponent
      ],
   exports: [ NewComponentComponent,
              New2Component,
             ChildComponentComponent]
    })

    export class Components { }
```

The template error is because of formGroup, You need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in your root module

```
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,

        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
```

Comment: I understand the point. But still it is throwing the same error

Comment: Sorry. Actually i did a mistake while posting the code. I forgot to change that part. I've updated my question

Comment: are you using it in the template of app -component can you share more code?

Comment: In my app component's template, I have 3 routerLinks. Component1, Component2, Component3. In Component1's template I'm using *ngIf and *ngFor. Parsing error is throwing only on Component1. Not in Component2 or Component3.

Comment: @JaowatRaihan The error is Related to the reactive form module